# Requested entity was not found. [404]

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope someone has some insight into this issue. I'm trying to execute script in google sheets. The script runs fine when manually executed. We need to use service account for this purpose. API executable was published, I have .p12 file for authentication, there is only 1 function to run and we're getting the 404. I'm using some c# code from DEVs site and that should work as per the article. Has anybody else run into this? Is there an example that shows how to do it correctly? This is what i've based my code on, to no avail... https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth
Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: Thanks Ares - my specific problem is that while following devs example code, I can't execute google script and receive the before mentioned 404 error.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more concise. What's the _specific_ programming problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use C# in GAS. Google Apps Script is based on Javascript. The link you provided shows how to code an example in .NET, which is neither GAS or C#, so I'm confused at why you would follow that example at all.

Regardless, any code that can be used in a Google Script site will say that it is for a .gs or an HTML file.

Remember that Google has many API's that work across multiple languages. GAS is what they want to push, but not every guide they make is aimed at GAS.

I assume the 404 is from using unreadable code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I'm not trying to write GAS in c#. I'm trying to call GAS thru the API using .Net code.

Comment: Well, that is more clear now, however, GAS is a scripting language, not an API. If you are trying to access, an API through .Net using the OAuth token, I'm sure this code might help (think maps or Gmail). But you will have to look at those API's reference pages, which will explain how to use those API's with .Net AFTER you have the OAuth token.